# How to symbolize points using a numbering system

Tags: labeling, symbology, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API version 4, is it possible to symbolize points using a numbering system (1-n) as in this mockup?

[image]

A [simple marker symbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-SimpleMarkerSymbol.html) or [picture marker symbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-PictureMarkerSymbol.html) can be used to generate the circles, but how can the numbered labels be generated within the circles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using a combination of [labelClass](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-LabelClass.html) to generate the labels on-the-fly, and a [SimpleRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-SimpleRenderer.html) to create the circles.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use CIMSymbol - and the documentation has a sample for exactly that scenario.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/cim-symbols/index.html

CIM symbols were introduced at version 4.12 and are used to display multi-layer vector symbols which can include data driven text.

Comment: thank you! This looks really promising